# can't add more than one armature?

Tags: rigging, rigify

i want to ask,
so i make more than 1 character in one scene and then i tried to generate rig for my second rig, it didn't want to. and it always go back to my first rig. 
i can't add controller to my second character

why? 
can't i make multiple rig then? or what? is it a bug?

and what do i have to do if i need move more than 2 character if i can't even generate my second rig controller?

can someone help me? thanks

i use (human) meta rig from blender 2.79b

update:

it doesn't work it still work the same it come back to my first rig

actually this is what happend when i generate my second character rig

[image]

[image]

[image]

and then i generate rig for my first character and then this happen it's like my second character didn't have rig and it overlapping with my first character but only the arrow controller there.

is it because i duplicate my first armature and then adjust it for the second one this is what happen or what?
[image]

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to go into Advanced options and select NEW:

[image]

Comment: it didn't work i add it on my question how it didn't work...

Comment: @Cezzlyn Rigify creates the rig always in the scene center, not where the mesh is, it works fine. You might have another issue by looking at your pictures and that is not all bones were generated for your second character - maybe names or parenting is changed from the metarig?